# CURL inside windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I'm trying to use CURL inside a windows batch file. I need to capture the response inside a variable but am struggling. I have tried several syntaxes and if I attempt to use curl_setopt I get an error about the Environment variable not being defined. Going back to basics I started with ...

```
set response = curl http://www.google.co.uk
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "response="
for /f "delims=" %%r in ('curl http://www.google.co.uk 2^>^&1') do (
  set response=!response!%NL%%%r 
)
echo %response%
endlocal
endlocal
```

Comment: Why the quotes in `set "response="` when `set response=` works just as well?

Comment: @ErikE: that ensures `String`