# Batch - String replacement with special characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to replace a string in a file using a batch file.

The string is:

```
),(
```

And I want to replace it by:

```
),
(
```

I found several posts, like this one : ["how-to-replace-substrings-in-windows-batch-file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273937) but the example uses a dummy string with no special characters.

Thank you !

**EDIT**

Context: I use `mysqldump` to extract a database and I would like every line of the insert command to be on a new line for more visibility.

I don't want to use `--extended-insert=false` because it slows down reinsertion of the backup.

**EDIT2**

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `dummytable` (`dummycolumn`) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
```

I want it to be:

```
INSERT INTO `dummytable` (`dummycolumn`) VALUES (1),
(2),
(3);
```

Comment: `\n` should be line feed or the real \n string?

Comment: are the quotes part of the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)

```
call replacer.bat "e?C:\content.txt" "\u0022),(\u0022" "\u0022),\u000a(\u0022"
```

**Edit** without the quotes:

```
call replacer.bat "e?C:\content.txt" "),(" "),\u000a("
```

windows style

```
call replacer.bat "e?C:\content.txt" "),(" "),\u000D\u000a("
```

you can check also [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and [JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which are more sophisticated tools

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET textFile=test.txt
TYPE NUL>tempOut.txt
FOR /F %%l IN (%textFile%) DO (
    SET line=%%l
    SET line=!line:"),("="),\n("!
    ECHO !line!>>tempOut.txt
)
MOVE /y tempOut.txt %textFile%
```

Comment: I think the OP wants line feed on the place of `\n`

Comment: I just tested your solution but it does not work for me, half of my file disappeared :/

Comment: Could you please post a part of your text file so that I can test it?

Comment: I added an example for you =)

Answer (score 0):

In batch if the pattern are always same you could deal with tokens and delims like this:

```dos
@echo off

(echo INSERT INTO `dummytable` (`dummycolumn`^) VALUES (1^),(2^),(3^);
)>%TEMP%\_file.tmp

(FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %%a IN (%TEMP%\_file.tmp) do (
    echo %%a,
    echo %%b,
    echo %%c
))>_output.txt
exit /b 0
```

output:

```dos
INSERT INTO `dummytable` (`dummycolumn`) VALUES (1),
(2),
(3);
```

**Edit**
I found another way from a npocmaka's post in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20516501/4070433)

```dos
@echo off

setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (%TEMP%\_file.tmp) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set line=!line:,(=,%NL%(!
    echo !line!
)

endlocal
endlocal
exit /b 0
```